# $_FILES array sometimes is empty

Tags: php, html, magento, magento-1.9

i have an issue with sending files form in magento CE 1.9.2.1. When i trying to attach files in php **$_FILES array is empty but sometimes not**. Please help me to find solution. Here is html form:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('quote/index/save', array('_secure'=>true)); ?>" id="get_a_quote" method="post" name="get_a_quote" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="wizard">
        <label for="attachment">Attachment</label>
        <input type="file" name="attachment[]" multiple="multiple" />
        <input id="submit" type="submit" name="save" value="Get A Quote" />
    </div>
</form>
```

in IndexController my save action code is:

```
print_r($_FILES); die;// result Array() but sometimes Array(bla bla bla)
```

My server info is:

```
post_max_size = 8M
upload_max_filesize = 16М
```

Comment: Did you check whether it is a file size problem? `post_max_size` should be at least the same as `upload_max_filesize`. Anything else doesn't make much sense.

Comment: files size what i want to upload is 400KB and sometimes they uploading fine but sometimes not due to empty $_FILES array

Comment: Are there any spaces or any non-alphanumeric characters in the filename? Did you turn on `error_reporting` and check for any errors or warnings?

Comment: Does the same file sometimes work and then sometime fail? Or is it certain files only failing?

Comment: maybe this iisue appear due to SSL sertificate ? my site use HTTPS